# Экран блокировки

Tags: android, android-sdk

Я пишу экран блокировки, но столкнулся со следующей проблемой: как заблокировать кнопки "home" и "back"? мне посоветовали сделать блокировщик экрана, как домашний экран по умолчанию, но и тут есть загвоздка: при попытке разблокировать экран заново запускается этот же экран блокировки, т.е. на рабочий стол не переходит (как я понимаю мой экран блокировки становится лаунчером), так вот: как можно сделать так, что бы при разблокировке телефона запускался дефолтный лаунчер?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, так, как никто мне не ответил, я нашел для себя выход: я отказался от затеи использовать активность как домашний экран, вместо этого я использую обычную активность, которая отслеживает, когда телефон уходит в сон, либо, когда телефон загружается и запускает активность, затем, руководствуясь данным видео (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBi8fjv90E4) я просто спрятал системные кнопки